# Amazon S3 and Cloud Front

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

How do I integrate Amazon Cloud Front and S3 in a photo sharing application?

I currently upload to S3, and return the cloudfront url but this has not been very successful because it appears there is a latency between s3 and cloudfront such that the returned url is not immediately valid.

Does any know how I can work around this?

Facebook uses Akamai and if I upload an image it is immediately available.

Would appreciate some ideas on this.

Comment: There is no "latency" between S3 and CloudFront.  Please provide examples, using the relevant output from a tool such as `curl -v` to document the responses that confirm what you are seeing.

Comment: Are you saying uploads to s3 are immediately distributed on cloudfront? I have to wait some minutes otherwise I am getting access denied. I use the Java Api to upload files.

Answer (score 1):

You must be trying to fetch the object *immediately* through cloudfront. I'm unsure why that might be, but you are hitting the limits of S3's [eventual consistency model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency).

When you upload an object, the message takes a tiny amount of time to propagate across the S3 service. Generally this is well under one second and is hard to detect. (in a previous <s>life</s> job, we found we could reasonably guarantee all files arrived within 10 seconds, and 99.9% within 1 second)

[Here's the official word from AWS; it's worth reading the whole page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel):

> A process writes a new object to Amazon S3 and immediately lists keys within its bucket. Until the change is fully propagated, the object might not appear in the list.

[There's a much longer discussion on this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786609/what-is-maximum-amazon-s3-replication-time-on-file-upload); assuming you are using the standard S3 bucket, you need to change your endpoint slightly to take advantage of the read-after-write model.

Further reading:
* [Instrumental: Why you should stop using the us-standard Region in S3. Right Now™](https://instrumentalapp.com/blog/why-you-should-stop-using-the-us-standard-region-in-s3-right-now/)
* [Read-After-Write Consistency in Amazon S3](http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/12/read-after-write-consistency-in-amazon.html) (from 2009, contains dated info)

One way you can debug/prove this is by calling `getObjectMetadata` right before your CloudFront call. It should fail in this case.