# S3 Key Not Present Immediatly After Listing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using Python and boto3 to work with S3.

I'm listing an S3 bucket and filtering by a prefix:

```
bucket = s3.Bucket(config.S3_BUCKET)
for s3_object in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="0000-00-00/", Delimiter="/"):
```

This gives me an iterable of S3 objects.

If I print the object I see:

> s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='validation', key=u'0000-00-00/1463665359.Vfc01I205aeM627249')

When I go to get the body though I get an exception:

```
content = s3_object.get()["Body"].read()
```

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when
>   calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.

So boto just gave me the key, but then it says it doesn't exist?

This doesn't happen for all keys. Just some. If I search for the invalid key in the AWS console it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's safe to assume you are using the 'standard' endpoint. All of this primarily applies to it, and not the regional endpoints. S3 is atomic and [eventually consistent](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2008/12/eventually_consistent.html). [The documentation gives several examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel), including this:

> A process writes a new object to Amazon S3 and **immediately lists keys within its bucket**. Until the change is fully propagated, **the object might not appear in the list**.

Occasionally delays of [many](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23794474/659298) [hours](http://www.stackdriver.com/eventual-consistency-really-eventual/) have been seen, and my anecdata agrees with [this statement](http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/12/read-after-write-consistency-in-amazon.html) that well over 99% of the data exists within 2 seconds.

You can enable read-after-write consistency, which "fixes" this, by changing your endpoint from `s3.amazonaws.com` to `s3-external-1.amazonaws.com`:

```
s3client = boto3.client('s3', endpoint_url='s3-external-1.amazonaws.com')
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on read-after-write consistency, that exactly solves my problem.

Comment: Cool. It's esoteric.

Comment: Worth noting that recent versions of boto3/botocore also have support for `s3-external-1` as a region name, so you can use `boto3.client('s3', region_name='s3-external-1')`, or the usual `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`, region in config file, etc.